# facebook app, friend data access token does not work

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token

A user successfully logs into the facebook app. However the app is not able to pull up the user's friend information. It can only return one friend's information who previously permitted the app to have her information.

I am using curl and access token to access my friends facebook data through an app. I am developing my app locally. It works those accounts of mine that I had before, but it does not work for new users. What could cause that?

Is that because I am developing on the localhost now? If yes, why does it work for couple of accounts that I have and not for other users which also have given permission to my app? I have also tried to access friends data using the access token I had and was not able to get any access to any data on the developer site.

```
$uri ="https://graph.facebook.com/".$friend_id."/books?access_token=".$params['access_token'];
$temp = json_decode(get_data($uri), true);
```

Comment: When you var_dump($temp) what are you getting? Are any errors being returned from the fb call?

Comment: I saw it returns Null for all friends except the one that give my website the permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Developing on localhost will cause problems with Facebook yes. You won't be able to authorise your app on Facebook.

If anything happens funny with Facebook Graph, make sure you're developng on the same server/url as listed in the "Basic" permissions tab. Otherwise things just may not work.

---

But your answer more appropriately relates to permissions: the previous "friend" has given permission for the app to get the data. So, even when connected as another user (or even not connected) you can get their data. But other users have not given permission, so you can't get data. Not needed if the data is "public" but they are needed is the data is not considered public.

Check you have the right extended permissions to query friends data - you can ask Friend A to authorise getting SOME data from friend B. In this case one friend gave you permissions for their own data, but check to see what other permissions you may need to get details from friends that have not authorised the app - and in some cases it isn't possible to get everything.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/